# How to deliver more than 500 certificate?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

I was created a template of achievement certification and i would like to send it to 500 persons,how can i write name's in the template and save it one by one using adobe illustrator ?

Comment: Do you have access to InDesign? This job is way easier in that software.

Comment: You'll likely want to do it using `data merge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Variables" panel (Window -> Variables) and import your data from XML or CSV.

This can be used to import text variables and/or different images.

There is a good "Learn More" linked from that panel:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/data-driven-graphics-templates-variables.html